# Suspected Rouche's Theorem Question?

Tags: complex-analysis

Part 1: Let $g$ be analytic in $|z|<1$ and $|g(z)|\leq 1$ for $|z|<1$. If $g(0)=g'(0)=0$, prove that $|g(z)|\leq|z|^2$ for $|z|<1$.

Part 2: Assume further that $|g(i/2)|=1/4$, anything we can say about $g(z)$?

---

My attempts:

For Part 1: I note that if $z=0$, $|g(z)|\leq|z|^2$ is trivially true. Thus henceforth we may assume $z\neq 0$, so $0<|z|<1$.

$$0=g'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{g(z)}{z}$$

By continuity of complex modulus, $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{|g(z)|}{|z|}=0.$$

After that I am stuck.

For Part 2: It seems vaguely to me related to Rouche's Theorem, but I haven't got any concrete ideas.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Hints: 1. Review the proof of the Schwarz Lemma; there you have $g(0) = 0,$ and you consider $g(z)/z.$  Here you look at $g(z)/z^2.$

2. Because of 1., the maximum modulus theorem finishes this off in one line.